# What can be said about the poles of tan(1/z)?

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

I came around the fact that $tan\frac{1}{z}$ has an essential singularity at $z=0$.
I followed the following steps:
$$tan(1/z)=\frac{sin(1/z)}{cos(1/z)} \\
cos(1/z) = 0 \implies 1/z=(2n+1)\pi/2 \implies z=2/\pi(2n+1) \\
$$
As $n$ tends to $\infty$, the sequence of zeroes of $cos(1/z)$ converge to $z=0$. Hence $z=0$ is not a isolated zero of $cos(1/z)$ and hence $z=0$ is an essential singularity  of $tan(1/z)$. 
It is also clear that $z=2/\pi(2n+1)$ are isolated singularities of $tan(1/z)$. 
Now, the next thing I want to do is to prove that $z=2/\pi(2n+1)$ are poles of $tan(1/z)$ and they are simple. How do I proceed for it?

Comment: $0$ is a [cluster point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolated_singularity#Nonisolated_singularities) (limit point of isolated singularities), not an essential singularity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, $0$ neither is nor isn't an essential singularity of $\tan\left(\frac1z\right)$. The classification of singularities into regular points, poles and essential singularities applyes only to *isolated* singularities, and $0$ is not an isolated singularity.

Now, if $z_0=\frac2{\pi(2n+1)}$ for some $n\in\Bbb N$, then $z_0$ is not a zero of $\sin\left(\frac1z\right)$ and it is a simple zero of $\cos\left(\frac1z\right)$ (since $\left(\cos\left(\frac1z\right)\right)'|_{z=z_0}\ne0$), and therefore $z_0$ is a simple pole of $\tan\left(\frac1z\right)$.

Comment: I thought that the singularities which aren't poles are essential singularities. Thanks for the clarification. But I dont understand how you inferred that $z_0$ is a simple pole of $tan(1/z)$ from the fact that it is a simple zero of $cos(1/z)$

Comment: If $f(z)=\frac{g(z)}{h(z)}$, $g(z_0)\ne0$, $h(z_0)=0$, and $h'(z_0)\ne0$, then near $z_0$, you have$$g(z)=a_0+a_1(z-z_0)+a_2(z-z_0)^2+\cdots,$$with $a_0=g(z_0)\ne0$ and$$h(z)=b_1(z-z_0)+b_2(z-z_0)^2+\cdots,$$with $b_1=h'(z_0)\ne0$. Therefore,\begin{align}f(z)&=\frac{a_0+a_1(z-z_0)+a_2(z-z_0)^2+\cdots}{b_1(z-z_0)+b_2(z-z_0)^2+\cdots}\\&=\frac1{z-z_0}\frac{a_0+a_1(z-z_0)+a_2(z-z_0)^2+\cdots}{b_1+b_2(z-z_0)+b_3(z-z_0)^2+\cdots}\end{align}

Comment: And$$\frac{a_0+a_1(z-z_0)+a_2(z-z_0)^2+\cdots}{b_1+b_2(z-z_0)+b_3(z-z_0)^2+\cdots}$$defines an analytic function near $z_0$ which maps $z_0$ into $\frac{a_0}{b_1}\ne0$. So, $f$ has a simple pole at $z_0$.

Comment: Thanks Jose. That is very elaborative!

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.